# how to value to integer VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I’m trying to create VBA that allows me to copy the one of a cell and paste over until end of the row in the same column. 
But I’m unable to figure out how this works, I have a total of 109 rows with 20 columns and in column “BD” that is an empty column and I want to put today date and fill up rest of the same column until end of row.

Please see the code at the bottom

```
Sub CopyInsert()

    Range("BD2").Select

    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=TODAY()"
    Range("BD2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

This code is working fine but I’m not getting the right result what these codes do is copy and paste over pass 109 rows mean is paste over up to around 2000 rows
My question is how can I copy and paste over until the end of the row like till row 109! If we have over 200 rows, how to copy and paste until end of the row, row 200 in one column! But not using (BD2:BD), I have tried (BD2:BD) and is paste over 109 rows is not stopped at the end of row.

many thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you [searched at all](https://www.google.com/search?q=vba+loop+through+range) for how to loop through a range?  Or [find last row](https://www.google.com/search?q=find+last+row+VBA)?

Comment: What does your question have to do with the (ungrammatical) title of the question (which seems to be about converting non-integer values to integers)? The question is unclear. For example, what does "end of the row in the same column" even mean?

Comment: sorry for not clear "end of the row in same column" mean copy cell (BD2) and pasted over same column until row 109, but not using (bd2:d) because this pass paste row 109.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you need to find the lastRow based on the column where the actual data is...

Try something like this:

```
With worksheets("mySheet")

    Dim lastRow as Long
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row 'this uses column A for example

    .Range("BD2:BD" & lastRow).Formula = "=TODAY()"

End With
```

Comment: Your rows and columns are in the wrong order on `lastRow`